How to obtain a solution to a system of equations using the method of successive approximations?
My question is not offtopic at all! It's about problem of syntax in Mathematica.
It is necessary to obtain an analytical solution to a system of equations using the method of successive approximations for $\alpha$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, where $z\Omega>2$.
$
            \delta=-\left(\frac{z\sin(\alpha)}{\cosh(\gamma)+\cos(\alpha)}+1\right)(\delta^2+\gamma^2)/\Omega,\\
            \gamma=\frac{z\sinh(\gamma)(\delta^2+\gamma^2)/\Omega}{\cosh(\gamma)+\cos(\alpha)},\\       \alpha=\beta\varepsilon+\delta.
$
The zero-th solution is
$\gamma^0=z\Omega$, $\delta^0=-\Omega$, $\alpha^0=\beta\varepsilon-\Omega$.
I'd like to get the 2nd and 3rd order solution of successive approximation and then expand in a Taylor series in terms of the parameter $z\Omega$.
If there was one equation here instead of three, I would just use Nestlist. I don't know how to act if there are several equations.

Please provide your Mathematica code. Do you assume \[CurlyEpsilon]<<1?

Please, at least type your equations in Mathematica. Otherwise your question will probably be closed.

The last example in the Nest documentation under Generalizations and Extensions may be helpful

I'll type equations a bit later. No, Epsilon is not small. $z\Omega>2$ to provide no zeros in denominator.

I deleted my answer because it doesn't do the expansion in $z \Omega$ but this is at least is how you could set up your system for NestList

I did to know @@#& combination. Looks weird

step@@#& means "Replace the head of the argument with step" so in our case it would take the argument {γ, δ, α} which has head List and replace it with head step giving step[γ, δ, α] and NestList now gets the result of step[γ, δ, α] and sets it as the new {γ, δ, α} and repeats

The system of equations to be solved using the method of successive approximations is given by:
$
        \delta = -\left(\frac{z \sin(\alpha)}{\cosh(\gamma) + \cos(\alpha)} + 1\right) \frac{\delta^2 + \gamma^2}{\Omega}
        $
$
        \gamma = \frac{z \sinh(\gamma) \frac{\delta^2 + \gamma^2}{\Omega}}{\cosh(\gamma) + \cos(\alpha)}
        $
$
        \alpha = \beta \varepsilon + \delta
        $
where:
$ \delta $, $ \gamma $, $ \alpha $ are the variables to be solved $ z $, $ \Omega $, $ \beta $, $ \varepsilon $ are parameters.
The initial zero-th order solutions are:
$
    \gamma^0 = z \Omega, \quad \delta^0 = -\Omega, \quad \alpha^0 = \beta \varepsilon - \Omega
    $
Step 1: Define the system of equations
ClearAll[z, Ω, α, β, ϵ, γ, δ]

(* Define parameters *)
Ω =.; (* Replace with your specific value *)
z =.; (* Replace with your specific value *)
β =.; (* Replace with your specific value *)
ϵ =.; (* Replace with your specific value *)

(* Initial zero-th order solutions *)
γ0 = z Ω;
δ0 = -Ω;
α0 = β ϵ - Ω;

(* System of equations *)
eqns = {
   δ == -((z Sin[α]/(Cosh[γ] + Cos[α]) + 1) (δ^2 + γ^2)/Ω),
   γ == (z Sinh[γ] (δ^2 + γ^2)/Ω)/(Cosh[γ] + Cos[α]),
   α == β ϵ + δ
   };

Step 2: Implement successive approximation method
We will use NestList to iteratively solve the equations to higher orders. Each iteration refines the solutions.
(* Function to perform one iteration of successive approximation *)
iterate[{γ_, δ_, α_}] := Module[{newγ, newδ, newα},
  newδ = δ /. First@Solve[eqns[[1]], δ];
  newγ = γ /. First@Solve[eqns[[2]], γ];
  newα = α /. First@Solve[eqns[[3]], α];
  {newγ, newδ, newα}
]

(* Perform successive approximations *)
order = 3; (* Number of orders to compute *)
solutions = NestList[iterate, {γ0, δ0, α0}, order - 1];

(* Extract the solutions at each order *)
γsolutions = solutions[[All, 1]];
δsolutions = solutions[[All, 2]];
αsolutions = solutions[[All, 3]];

(* Display solutions *)
TableForm[Transpose[{Range[0, order - 1], γsolutions, δsolutions, αsolutions}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Order", "γ", "δ", "α"}}]

Step 3: Expand in a Taylor series with respect to $z\Omega$
To expand the solutions in a Taylor series around $z\Omega$, assuming $z\Omega$ is small, we can use Series
(* Small parameter for expansion *)
smallParameter = $z\Omega$;

(* Perform Taylor series expansion *)
seriesExpansion = Table[
  {Series[γsolutions[[i]], {z Ω, 0, 2}], 
   Series[δsolutions[[i]], {z Ω, 0, 2}], 
   Series[αsolutions[[i]], {z Ω, 0, 2}]},
  {i, Length[solutions]}
];

(* Display the Taylor series expansions *)
TableForm[Transpose[{Range[0, order - 1], seriesExpansion}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"Order", "γ", "δ", "α"}}]


WOW. You did a great job.

I copy pasted your code in MA notebook and got a lot of errors. The first one is Solve::ivar: -[CapitalOmega] is not a valid variable.

What does "Replace with your specific value" mean? Why is it needed?

Series[#, {z Ω, 0, 2}]& is going to generate a General::ivar message because z Ω is not a valid variable. You might be able to at least collect powers of z  Ω for the solutions' numerators and denominators using Michael E2's answer here
